# MySQL Friend Table Two-Way Unique Index

Tags: php, mysql

My `user` table is something like:

```
Table: users
UserID      Username
1            'Tom'
2            'x1x'
3            'Google'
```

And my current DB design for my `friends` table is:

```
Table: user_relationships
relationship_id    to_user_id     by_user_id    status   date
1                     1              2             1     CURDATE()
2                     1              3             2     CURDATE()
3                     3              2             3     CURDATE()
```

The status column is:

```
1 - Friends
2 - Pending Request
3 - Ignored
```

And the purpose of the date column is to find how long user A and user B have been friends. The thing is, when Tom(id: 1) becomes friends with x1x (id: 2), Tom should not be able to send a friend request to x1x (id: 2). Likewise, Tom(id: 1) should not be able to send a friend to Google(id: 3). (instead an option of accepting should be given). I put a unique constraint on `to_user_id` and `by_user_id`, but the unique constraint is not both ways as in:

```
Table: user_relationships
relationship_id    to_user_id     by_user_id    status   date
1                     1              2             1     CURDATE()
2                     1              3             2     CURDATE()
3                     3              2             3     CURDATE()
4                     2              1             2     CURDATE()
```

Relationship ID 4 should NOT be allowed, and the query should be something like

```
INSERT INTO ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE relationship_id = relationship_id
```

But again, the unique constraint is not two way. How can I accomplish this? I really don't want to have to do

```
SELECT .... WHERE to_user_id = x AND by_user_id = y OR to_user_id = y AND by_user_id = x
```

To check for existence and then `INSERT` based on that. Is there a systematic flaw in my DB design for this that may be causing this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are only interested in "there is a relationship between two users", you could sort the user IDs such that `to_user_id` is the smaller ID and and `by_user_id` is the greater ID or the other way around.

If you are interested in "who added whom", you can add two new columns `user_1` and `user_2` and do what I described above using the two new columns.

If the two IDs are sorted, a single unique key does what you want.

You can use the MySQL function [`GREATEST()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_greatest) and [`LEAST()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_least) to simplify your insert queries.

If this does not work for you, you can try to use triggers, to check if the input should be made or not, but I think this is a very ugly way and maybe you get problems with reading and writing from the same table.

Comment: Can't I just have: to_user_id, from_user_id using your (ingenious) recommended lower id on the left and larger on the right than have another column called sent_id to identify the user who made the request? Or should I make another table with relationship_id and sent_id?

Comment: @PhilipTsang Sure. To get the unique key work, you have to use two columns with sorted IDs. All other things are open to you.